# How to get date and time with PHP,

Tags: php, date

I used to get the date and time like this in PHP:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

$info = getdate();
$date = $info['mday'];
$month = $info['mon'];
$year = $info['year'];
$hour = $info['hours'];
$min = $info['minutes'];
$sec = $info['seconds'];

$time = "D/M/Y= $date/$month/$year H/M/S= $hour:$min:$sec";
```

Although, now whenever I run it, $time ends up: "0".

Is there an alternative to this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function to format a date/time.

```
echo date('\D/\M/\Y= d/m/Y \H/\M/\S= G:m:s');
```

To use a literal character ("D" for example), you must escape it.

Comment: odd though,... It seemed to have worked without needing to escape a couple weeks ago.